# Python3 Tkinter - multiple frames in their own classes and handling resizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am trying to understand how resizing works. The basic demos for resizing show how an application with a single frame and a single button in that frame.  I am trying to expand on this by having some prebuilt frames as a class that I can reuse over and over in the main frame of the application. This is where I get lost on how to get them to resize with the main window resizing. Sorry for the crappy code ahead of time, I am actually pretty confused about setting all this GUI stuff up coming from pure script based programs before this.

```
import tkinter as tk

# reusable class of a frame that will create a single row with 4 columns containing a label, entry, label, and button
class FrameWithEntryAndLabelAndErrorAndButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, row_text):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.create_widgets(row_text)

    def create_widgets(self, row_text):
        self.label_entry = tk.Label(self, text=f'{row_text} Dir')
        self.label_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.entry_box = tk.Entry(self, width = 100)
        self.entry_box.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.label_error = tk.Label(self, text=f'{row_text} ErrorMessage')
        self.label_error.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.directory_search_button = tk.Button(self, text=f'{row_text} OpenDir')
        self.directory_search_button.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=tk.EW)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.resizable(1, 1)
        self.parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.inputframe = FrameWithEntryAndLabelAndErrorAndButton(self, 'row0')
        self.inputframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.inputframe2 = FrameWithEntryAndLabelAndErrorAndButton(self, 'row1')
        self.inputframe2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

initial run:

[image]

after resize:

[image]

If possible, I would like the entry box to grow the most (I thought that Is what the weight was supposed to do for that column in the custom class), and the labels to maybe grow less, etc.

Edit to add:

Thanks to a reddit poster who noticed in my Application class, I never had a columnconfigure call on itself to set the weight on column 0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `tkinter`. You will have to use TTK. I also removed `tk.` It is straight forward for you. I changed it using the same code as yours.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class FrameWithEntryAndLabelAndErrorAndButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, row_text):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.create_widgets(row_text)

    def create_widgets(self, row_text):
        self.label_entry = Label(self, text=f'{row_text} Dir')
        self.label_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=EW)
        self.entry_box = Entry(self, width = 100)
        self.entry_box.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=EW)
        self.label_error = Label(self, text=f'{row_text} ErrorMessage')
        self.label_error.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=EW)
        self.directory_search_button = Button(self, text=f'{row_text} OpenDir')
        self.directory_search_button.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=EW)


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.resizable(1, 1)
        self.parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.inputframe = FrameWithEntryAndLabelAndErrorAndButton(self, 'row0')
        self.inputframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.inputframe2 = FrameWithEntryAndLabelAndErrorAndButton(self, 'row1')
        self.inputframe2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=NSEW)


root = Tk () 
app = Application(root)
app.master.title('Sample application')
root.resizable (False, False)  
mainloop ()
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work with tk as well.  I was missing the columnconfigure for the Application class on itself (thank you to a reddit poster who noticed this for me.